# PHP MVC + Router and Redirect issue

Tags: php, model-view-controller, redirect, router

I have an odd issue that I can not for the life of me figure out. First of all I have developed a PHP MVC framework from scratch. The problem I am having is that I am getting a header redirect execution after an exit() call.

Here is a high level view of the routing process:

1. REQUEST_URI is stripped apart and the requested controller, method, and any arguments are set to variables to be used later in the script.
2. The router.php checks to make sure if the requested controller actually exists, if it doesn't then it returns false but if everything checks out then it returns true
3. If it returns true, it executes the requested controller, method, and any arguments.
4. If it returns false then the router will send a redirect to a custom 404 page. This uses PHP's header() function and there is an exit() after the header("Location: *");

Step 4 is where the problem occurs. The requested controller exists so it executed and the requested view exists so it loads everything correctly but then it executes the redirect even though an exit() is called after successfully loading the view.

Is there any reason why the router would continue on and fire the redirect?

Comment: Firstly please post some code, we are not that mighty to guess everything.

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk True. But, can you be mighty and earn 300 points for helping with my question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42172228/is-this-how-an-mvc-router-class-typically-works

Comment: @Lark How's that framework going? is there anything you can help me with? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42172228/is-this-how-an-mvc-router-class-typically-works

Comment: @Lark in the system I'm tinkering with, I move all Router validation into a separate class called RouterValidator. I have posted code and UML diagrams here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42172228/is-this-how-a-php-mvc-router-class-works-in-laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to guess (as per @Tomasz :), but even if you `exit()` the browser is going to respect any http headers it gets, including a Location.

In fact in something similar I do, on any errors I send a redirect header and then do an `exit` to make sure execution doesn't continue in the controller *after* the redirect.

Comment: I would love to hear any and all thoughts about my problem with creating a routing class. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42172228/is-this-how-an-mvc-router-class-typically-works